# editing hue and/or saturation of a CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, hue

is it possible to change hue and/or saturation of a CCSprite which texture is already loaded a.png ?
looking something like this
eg:

```
[CCSprite1 spriteWithImage@"img1.png"];
[CCSprite1 setHue:150];//<<<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only change opacity and color (tint).

That is unless you write a custom fragment shader.